# Storm using c++ ,the Storm will be blocked sometimes

Tags: c++, apache-storm

my question is

1. When I use C++ to implement the Spout and the Bolt of the Storm through the ShellSpout and ShellBolt, the Bolt that calls C++ will be blocked sometimes.
2. The bolt will subscribe the stream of the Spout which implements with C++, and the grouping method is FieldGrouping.
3. Both of the components hava only one field, there will be a JSON value emitted to the next part.
4. But, there will be ok when I use only one of them, that is I use the C++ Spout and Java Bolt, or I use the Java Spout and C++ Bolt.

Can anyone help me?

P.S. the C++ storm code is C++ WRAPPER FOR STORM, where the website is http://demeter.inf.ed.ac.uk/cross/stormcpp.html.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you add more details? What does "blocked" mean? Who blocks?

Comment: the main method that creates the topology and runs the topology on a local mode will be blocked when these are one c++ Spout and one c++ Bolt,the c++ Bolt subscribes the c++ Spout.
sometimes I must terminate the main method manually on eclipse.
have you met the question ever?

Comment: UNfortunatelly it is still not clear. Try to show us your code. And try to explain, how to reproduce this problem on our side.